# Inkscape 0.92 'Stroke to Path' not working on B-splines

Tags: inkscape, stroke, bezier-curve

I have a design using B-splines, which I need to convert to a path, because it will need to be surrounded by a stroke in a separate colour.

[image: A thick, curved line, entering the image on the left border, protruding to the top right corner, and exiting on the lower border]

However, when I use the 'stroke to path ' (Ctrl + Alt + C) tool, the curve changes shape. It stops being rounded and instead becomes a sharp-cornered line around the B-spline's control points.

[image: A thick line, following the same general direction as the one in the previous image, but this time with sharp corners]

How should I go about achieving my desired effect?

Answer (score 3):

Apply at first Object to Path to make it Bezier curve. Apply Stroke to Path after it.

Comment: Explanation: B-Spline is a path effect. It is applied on top of the path data, and needs to be made a path itself first.